# Getting dynamic selector in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am working on Cypress and want to get a dynamic selector that always changes.
For example,

```js
<div class="Select-value">
 <input id = "react-select-9--value">
```

I want to get this input value but the number "9" for the ID changes every time I run the test. There is no other selector I can pick for this and there are other inputs on the same page with IDs like `react-select-10--value`, `react-select-11--value`.

What is the right way to get this type of selector in Cypress?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you share the html structure of this, we can offer better long term solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aim for a relative element.

The only one shown above is the `<div>`, so using that as an example

```js
cy.get('div[class="Select-value"]')
  .find('[id^="react-select"]')       // ^= means "starts-with"
  .eq(0)                              // first one, because it looks like that above
```

Post a bigger example of the HTML if that's no good for you.